# Fake API with data to test my user interface in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am building a user interface in angularjs and I want to test my API signature on some remote server that responds according to the signature.
For example GET request    api/DocumentType/GetAll returns a JSON that I know the format and use.

I have created APIs with [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) Chrome tool but it test the API not the client.
But me I don't care about the API. I want to test my client for the specific API with specified signature.
So is there any tool that I can create the API format, response and the data to fetch so that I can test my UI.

I have also tested JSON placeholder but it does not support API creation and data hosting. Most of all I need the free one.

Comment: You can use $httpbackend to mock $http request and test your front end against it

Comment: try api-now on github. If you have nodejs, just run $ npx api-now

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Angular ApiMock](http://johansson.jp/angular-apimock/#/) to fake an API and focus on the UI code. It works by having a static JSON file in a URL that matches your API somewhat, and then setting a `?apimock=true` query on your browser or on individual `$http` calls so you can easily flip between the real API and mock on any environment.

Check the demo page first [without the flag](http://johansson.jp/angular-apimock/#/demo-simple) and then [with the flag](http://johansson.jp/angular-apimock/#/demo-simple?apimock).

(Full disclosure: I'm one of the creators of this library)

Edit: This works well with the other answer because you can reuse the static JSON file for Karma or other test runners.

Answer (score 1):

Try karma + jasmine for front end testing using $httpbackend.

Comment: i will try that ,I was building visual studio so I never used karma + jasmine anyway if  there is a tool online may be

Comment: keep the sample data and use the unit against it instead of hitting the api, if you just want to test if your unit acts properly to the response data

Answer (score 0):

[Atmo](https://github.com/Raathigesh/Atmo) could be an ideal solution for your requirement.